# jquery.steps and validation not working - form content not visible (invisible)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-steps

I already asked this question once, and got a few useful replies, marked it as answered and applied everything. It *seemed* like it worked, but sadly it doesnt.

The problem is:
The forms within the different steps fields are empty.
Well, I can't tell if every step is empty since I cant see and enter anything in the first step and therefore cant procede to the next step since the validations *seems* to be working.

I dont know why. I am sticking to the example given on the jquery steps page:
http://www.jquery-steps.com/Examples#advanced-form

It's exaclty the same code BUT:
My forms are empty. It looks like this:
[image: empty forms with jquery steps]

My Code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/Scripts/jquery.steps.js"></script>
        <link href="/Content/jquery.steps.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="example-advanced-form" action="#">
            <h3>Account</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Account Information</legend>

                <label for="userName-2">User name *</label>
                <input id="userName-2" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
                <label for="password-2">Password *</label>
                <input id="password-2" name="password" type="text" class="required">
                <label for="confirm-2">Confirm Password *</label>
                <input id="confirm-2" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
                <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
            </fieldset>

            <h3>Profile</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Profile Information</legend>

                <label for="name-2">First name *</label>
                <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="required">
                <label for="surname-2">Last name *</label>
                <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
                <label for="email-2">Email *</label>
                <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
                <label for="address-2">Address</label>
                <input id="address-2" name="address" type="text">
                <label for="age-2">Age (The warning step will show up if age is less than 18) *</label>
                <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="required number">
                <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
            </fieldset>

            <h3>Warning</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>You are to young</legend>

                <p>Please go away ;-)</p>
            </fieldset>

            <h3>Finish</h3>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>

                <input id="acceptTerms-2" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms-2">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </body>

    <script>
        var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();

        form.steps({
            headerTag: "h3",
            bodyTag: "fieldset",
            transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
            onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
                if (currentIndex > newIndex) {
                    return true;
                }
                // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
                if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18) {
                    return false;
                }
                // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
                if (currentIndex < newIndex) {
                    // To remove error styles
                    form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
                    form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
                }
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
                return form.valid();
            },
            onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
                // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
                if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18) {
                    form.steps("next");
                }
                // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
                if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3) {
                    form.steps("previous");
                }
            },
            onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
                form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
                return form.valid();
            },
            onFinished: function (event, currentIndex) {
                alert("Submitted!");
            }
        }).validate({
            errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
            rules: {
                confirm: {
                    equalTo: "#password-2"
                }
            }
        });
     </script>

</html>
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.content` doesn't appear to have any width (look at the tooltip in the upper right-hand corner of your last screenshot). Give it some width:

```css
.wizard > .content {
    ...
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Seems like that is it!

Comment: But its still not working in IE. Do you have any ideas why? Chrome works now, Firefox worked all the time, but not IE.

Comment: It's hard to say without having something to interact with. Can you reduce your problem and extract the code so it can be run either here on StackOverflow or using a service like [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: Its working now.. dont ask why becaue I certainly dont know the answer to that :)

Answer (score 0):

I have included below CSS file from original Github source code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
```

And form is displayed in Chrome and IE.

Comment: Please explain your answer, the code itself isn't usually enough to show what the problem is.